# Hector-getting columns as list with ColumnFamilyResult

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am using templates which i like very much but didnt see a straight forward way to get a list from the result so wrote something like this. it works but probably not very efficient. with the methods i found i have to get the column name and then use that to extract the value.

is there a better way?
thanks

```
HSlicePredicate<String> slice=new HSlicePredicate<String>(StringSerializer.get());
            slice.setCount(pagesize+1);
            slice.setStartOn(startUserKey);
            ColumnFamilyResult<UUID, String> res = blogFollowingUsersTemplate.queryColumns(blogId,slice);

            BlogFollowingUsers users=new BlogFollowingUsers();
            users.setBlogId(blogId);
            List<UserCompact> list=new ArrayList<UserCompact>();
            for (Iterator iterator = res.getColumnNames().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                list.add((UserCompact) Json.fromJson(res.getString(iterator.next().toString()),UserCompact.class));
            }
            users.setUsers(list);

            return users;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is better. found it on one of the examples..

```
SliceQuery<UUID, String, String> query = HFactory.createSliceQuery(daoUtil.getKeyspace(), UUIDSerializer.get(),
                StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get()).
                setKey(blogId).setColumnFamily("BlogFollowingUsers");

        ColumnSliceIterator<UUID, String, String> iterator = 
                new ColumnSliceIterator<UUID, String, String>(query, startUserKey, "", false, pagesize+1);

        BlogFollowingUsers users=new BlogFollowingUsers();
        users.setBlogId(blogId);
        List<UserCompact> list=new ArrayList<UserCompact>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            list.add((UserCompact) Json.fromJson(iterator.next().getValue(), UserCompact.class));
        }
        users.setUsers(list);
        return users;
```